# non-negative solution to system of linear equations

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

I have a collection of n vectors **P**. I have a vector C. I'd like to know if C can be expressed as a combination of some, or all of the vectors in **P**. The coefficients don't need to be integers, **but must be non-zero**.

It's that constraint: non-zero part, which I'm stuck on.

I'd also appreciate a hint at how to implement this algorithmically if someone is knowledgeable ... I have the Knuth books, and Numerical Recipes in C, if those provide a short-hand.

Comment: Non-negative or non-zero?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming should solve this

Comment: Yes! Non-negative; sorry about that. Your link was very helpful.